# Как сделать графический календарь в форме?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Есть форма, и 2 поля с масками 99-99-9999 (день-месяц-год), чтобы не вводить дату вручную с клавиатуры, можно как-то сделать чтобы при нажатии к примеру на поле выскакивал календарь ну и при выборе конкретной даты эта сама дата отображалась в input.

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше воспользоваться нативными средствами браузера: [`<input type="date" />`](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/data-i-vremya)?
Там и календарь, и ввести чушь нельзя.

Comment: ...и [работает только в Хроме](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). :)

Comment: I know. Лучше, чем ничего :)

Answer (score 0):

В интернете можно найти много плагинов календарей написанных на js, к примеру, https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас используется jQuery, то может Вам стоит попробовать jQuery UI? Вы можете подключить не весь, а только те виджеты, которые Вам нужны, например календарь: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/